# Liquibase: unable to extract data to changelog file

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm sure this seems obvious to experienced Liquibase users. I want to extract the data from a simple two table database to an xml file. The command I am running is:

```
java -cp "liquibase.jar;mysql-connector-java/*" "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main" --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings --username=myusername --password=mypassword --changeLogFile="C:\temp\category_data.xml" --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

Running this command produces a basically empty xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd"/>
```

The command output is:

```
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading tables for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading views for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading foreign keys for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading primary keys for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading columns for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading unique constraints for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Reading indexes for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: Sequences not supported for root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dti_subcat_mappings ...
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: C:\temp\category_data.xml exists, appending
INFO 8/31/13 8:57 PM:liquibase: No changes found, nothing to do
Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful
```

Comment: ..oh, and yes both tables have data in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following H2 database example works for me:

```
$ java -cp liquibase-core-3.0.3.jar:h2-1.3.173.jar:snakeyaml-1.12.jar \
       liquibase.integration.commandline.Main \
       --url=jdbc:h2:db/scottTiger \
       --driver=org.h2.Driver \
       --username=user \
       --password=pass \
       --changeLogFile=data.xml \
       --diffTypes=data \
       generateChangeLog
INFO 01/09/13 09:17:liquibase: data.xml does not exist, creating
Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful
```

Couple of questions:

- You appear to be using version 2.0 (changeset declaration). Have you tried upgrading to 3.0?
- Are you certain you are connecting to the correct schema?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that the issue was that I had auto-commit off and my insert statements on the two tables were not commited. Marking this answer as correct since you made me go back and look at the schema tables directly :)